# Книги по System.Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Посоветуйте книги для углубленного изучения рефлексии.

Comment: У c# отличнейшая документация, в которой много чего написано интересного и полезного, стоит начать как минимум с нее. А вообще, мой вам совет, не будьте теоретиком, идите сразу и практикуйтесь, решайте конкретную задачу, подбирайте к ней конкретный подход. Поверьте, даже если вы выучите все из доступного, без практики, это будет пустая трата времени, где вы еще и половину выучите того, что ни разу в жизни не примените.

Comment: РЕФЛЕКСИЯ. ВЛАДИМИР АЛЕКСАНДРОВИЧ ЛЕФЕВР. https://knigamir.com/catalog/psikhologiya_ID4/refleksiya-lefevr-v-a_ID123489/

Comment: @rotabor хорошая шутка

Comment: Вообще рефлексия - это набор костылей для добавления динамики там, где статическая типизация вставляет палки в колёса. Глубоко там изучать нечего и незачем. Достаточно поверхностных знаний для понимания что к чему. Берите класс `Type` и изучайте его свойства и методы, там во-первых не много, во-вторых не сложно. Ну вдобавок ко всему там где можно обойтись без рефлексии - нужно обходиться без неё, примерно такая философия. Рефлексия - это набор сложных и медленных по производительности механизмов, а медленный код мало кто хочет писать.